# Knockout 'if' binding that 'unwraps' a child script

Tags: knockout.js

The knockoutjs `if` binding can be used to show or hide some HTML based on a condition.

However the browser will still 'see' and parse anything inside the `if` binding before knockout has had a chance to apply bindings. If the contents is an image then that image may get downloaded by the browser even if it would be immediately hidden.

This can be a problem on mobile devices.

I realize one way to solve this problem is using data binding on the image tag, which won't set the source until knockout has ran the bindings:

```
 <img data-bind="attr: {'src': .....}"/>
```

For the purpose of this question I don't want to do that (the contents is much more complicated than a single image). So another solution is to use template binding *within* an `if` binding like this :

```
 <!-- ko if: model.banner() == 'cat' -->

    <script type="text/html" id="cat_header">
        <figure>
            <img src="https://largeimages.com/cat.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
        </figure>
    </script>

    <!-- ko template: { name: 'cat_header' } --><!-- /ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
```

The `script` tag is ignored by the browser so the image isn't downloaded, until the bindings are applied and an instance of the template is rendered.

This works just fine, but I feel is a little klunky.

What I'd really like to do is something much simpler with a new binding that automatically unwraps the template from the script tag :

```
 <!-- ko if2: model.banner() == 'cat' -->

    <script type="text/html">
        <figure>
            <img src="https://largeimages.com/cat.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
        </figure>
    </script>

 <!-- /ko -->
```

Or perhaps this which is even shorter:

```
    <script type="text/html" data-bind="if2: model.banner() == 'cat'">
        <figure>
            <img src="https://largeimages.com/cat.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
        </figure>
    </script>
```

I just don't have enough skill in knockout to be able to write the `if2` binding, plus I would have really thought somebody else had already done this.

So if anybody has already done this, or it is relatively simple to do I think it would be very useful.

Comment: To avoid that, you could also bind the src attribute, by putting a "#" by default and the actual url at the time you want to display the image.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve with the custom if2 binding, but i dont think it is a good idea. Actually the idea of using template binding is pretty good, with a little modification, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering: I don't really see the need for such a markup. But I'll try to help without questioning *why* you want to do it as you described:

The markup you want to use is this:

```
<script type="text/html" data-bind="if2: model.banner() == 'cat'">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://largeimages.com/cat.jpg" width="1920" height="1080">
    </figure>
</script>
```

The browser will not look at the content, but knockout *will* apply data-binds to this type of node: a good start.

I figured that what we're trying to do boils down to this:

1. Once the `if` binding value returns `true`, swap out the script tag for a div
2. Once the div is in the document, apply the original `if` data-bind.

So I wrote a custom binding handler that does those two things.

*1. Wait until the binding's value returns true for the first time:*

```
 init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var initialized = false;

  ko.computed(function() { 
    if (!initialized && ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
```

*2. Copy the contents of the script node to a virtual div*

```
      var scriptTag = element;
      var replacementDiv = document.createElement("div");
      replacementDiv.innerHTML = scriptTag.innerHTML;
```

*3. Apply the original binding with our virtual div instead of the script node*

```
      ko.bindingHandlers.if.init.call(null, 
        replacementDiv, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
```

*4. Inject the virtual div into the DOM and get rid of the script node*

```
      scriptTag.parentElement.replaceChild(replacementDiv, scriptTag);
```

*5. Wrap up*

```
      initialized = true;
    }
  }, null, { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element });

  return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
```

A (hopefully) working example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.if2 = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var initialized = false;

    ko.computed(function() {
      if (!initialized && ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
        var scriptTag = element;
        var replacementDiv = document.createElement("div");
        replacementDiv.innerHTML = scriptTag.innerHTML;

        ko.bindingHandlers.if.init.call(null, replacementDiv, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);

        scriptTag.parentElement.replaceChild(replacementDiv, scriptTag);
        initialized = true;
      }
    }, null, {
      disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
    });

    return {
      controlsDescendantBindings: true
    };
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({
  toggled: ko.observable(false)
})
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" data-bind="if2: toggled">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg">
</script>
<div data-bind="text: toggled"></div>
<button data-bind="click: toggled.bind(null, !toggled())">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ko template is actually a good idea, altough it should more likely serve the purpose of rendering some part of html that you use repeatedly, not only once. That beeing said, i would make the template more general (i suppose you may want to use similar template for other images too), so it accepts a js class representing let´s say an image in this case.

```
function AnimalImage(){
    var self = this;
    self.imageUrl = null;
    // plus any other attributes you may want to specify for the image

    self.init = function(imageUrl){
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
} 

<script type="text/html" id="animal_header">
    <figure>
        <img data-bind="attr: {'src': imageUrl}" width="1920" height="1080">
    </figure>
</script>
```

Then if you would want to show multiple images, you can use the 'foreach' parameter in template binding, which accepts observableArray of the objects that binds to the template

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: 'animal_header', foreach: animals }'>                                       
</div>
```

in viewmodel

```
self.animals = ko.observableArray();

var cat = new AnimalImage();
cat.init("https://largeimages.com/cat.jpg");
self.animals.push(cat);

var chicken = new AnimalImage();
chicken.init("https://largeimages.com/chicken.jpg");
self.animals.push(chicken);
```

Or for using the template for a single object multple times

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: 'animal_header', data: cat }'>                                       
</div>
<div data-bind='template: { name: 'animal_header', data: chicken }'>                                       
</div>
```

in viewmodel

```
self.chicken = ko.observable();
self.cat = ko.observable();

var cat = new AnimalImage();
cat.init("https://largeimages.com/cat.jpg");
self.cat(cat);

var chicken = new AnimalImage();
chicken.init("https://largeimages.com/chicken.jpg");
self.chicken(chicken);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is forever old, but if you're only trying to hide content until bindings are rendered, then you don't need to hide it in a one-time template.

Instead, just put what you're hiding in a `<div style="display: none" data-bind="visible: true">`.  Until knockout bindings are applied, it won't show.